# Use `vector<A>::size_type ix` to index `vector<B>`

Tags: c++, vector, size-type

This may be a trivial question. Usually, I need to define local `std::vector`s like `vector<int>`, `vector<double>` etc to store some intermediate values for a `vector<A>` where `A` is a self-defined class. These local `vector`s are supposed to have the ***same size*** as the `vector<A>`.

The problem is, when I write some `for` to assign values from `vector<A>` to the local `vector`s, is it bad practice to write it like (PS: the size of `vect_a` remains unchanged in the loop.)

```
vector<A> vect_a;
vector<int> local_vect;
...
for (vector<A>::size_type ix = 0; ix != vect_a.size(); ++ix) {
    local_vect[ix] = vect_a[ix].get_mem_var();
    ...
}
```

where `get_mem_var()` simply returns the `int mem_var` of `A`. Specifically, my concern is, `local_vect` is of `vector<int>`, not `vector<A>`, but it still uses `ix`, which is of `vector<A>::size_type` instead of `vector<int>::size_type`.

Sometimes I make it a bit more complex, like

```
for (struct {vector<A>::size_type ix; vector<int>::size_type iy;}
        gi = {0, 0}; gi.ix != vect_a.size(); ++gi.ix, ++gi.iy) {
    local_vect[gi.iy] = vect_a[gi.ix].get_mem_var();
    ...
}
```

But it feels redundant and unnecessary. I've heard `size_type` is often simply `size_t`, and using `vector<A>::size_type ix` for indexing `vector<int> local_vect` may just be OK. But is this bad practice in some way? A more general question is, is it OK to use `vector<A>::size_type ix` to index `vector<A>` and `vector<B>` (`A` and `B` can be built-in or user-defined) if we know `vector<A>` and `vector<B>` are supposed to have the same size?

Comment: You can still check something like `static_assert(std::is_same<vector<A>::size_type, vector<int>::size_type>::value, "type differ");`.

Comment: If you're really worried you could static_assert to check that they're the same size (or at least that `A`'s is bigger)... in practice I think you will find that this type is always `std::size_t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realistically, `std::vector<T>::size_type` is likely to be the same for any `T`, and so this isn't something that you need to worry about.

You can avoid worrying about this however by using `std::transform`, for example something like:

```
vector<A> vect_a;
vector<int> local_vect;

std::transform(std::begin(vect_a), std::begin(vect_b), std::begin(local_vect),
               [] (const A& a) { return a.get_mem_var(); });
```

Comment: I'd use `std::mem_fun_ref(&A::get_mem_var);` instead of the lambda.